# Ubuntu Enterprise Server 16.04 z/linux

Tags: beta

I am looking for a forum or another method to ask questions about Ubuntu Enterprise Server 16.04.  This is the server z/linux version of Ubuntu built for the mainframe.  I am also looking for documentation.

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on [Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.